# How to open relative path in VS Code when indexing is still in progress

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have large workspaces on a remote filesystem that takes over a day to finish indexing in VS Code. Once it finishes indexing I can open a file quickly using a relative path using Ctrl+P, pasting the path, and pressing Enter. But while waiting for indexing, after I paste the path into the Ctrl+P entry window, there is a little progress bar and nothing happens.

Is there another way to open a file given the relative path name (relative to the openend folder), or perhaps an extension that allows this without combining the two features of opening relative paths with searching for files?

Comment: I haven't tried this myself but you could look at this setting in vscode in settings.json: files.watcherExclude

Comment: what about using the `File: Open File` command in the command palette (or its default keybinding) (possibly with `"files.simpleDialog.enable": true` in settings.json)? Does that work?